Is there a specific type for cloudwatch alarm event in @types/aws-lambda package?
Cloudwatch alarm triggers SNS topic to which I have lambda subscribed. This lambda is written in typescript.
Below is an example event received in lambda. Notice the outer object is of SNS event. This SNS event has the cloudwatch alarm event embedded inside it in the Message field.
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "EventSource": "aws:sns",
      "EventVersion": "1.0",
      "EventSubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:Alarm-test:db99f3fe-1c4b",
      "Sns": {
        "Type": "Notification",
        "MessageId": "9921c85a-6f59-50c0",
        "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:4990:Alarm-test",
        "Subject": "ALARM: \"cpu-mon\" in US East (Ohio)",
        "Message": "{\"AlarmName\":\"cpu-mon\",\"AlarmDescription\":\"Alarm when CPU exceeds 70 percent\",\"AWSAccountId\":\"000000000\",\"NewStateValue\":\"ALARM\",\"NewStateReason\":\"Threshold Crossed: 2 out of the last 2 datapoints [99.8333333333333 (26/08/19 19:19:00), 99.1803278688525 (26/08/19 19:18:00)] were greater than the threshold (70.0) (minimum 2 datapoints for OK -> ALARM transition).\",\"StateChangeTime\":\"2019-08-26T19:20:52.350+0000\",\"Region\":\"US East (Ohio)\",\"OldStateValue\":\"OK\",\"Trigger\":{\"MetricName\":\"CPUUtilization\",\"Namespace\":\"AWS/EC2\",\"StatisticType\":\"Statistic\",\"Statistic\":\"AVERAGE\",\"Unit\":\"Percent\",\"Dimensions\":[{\"value\":\"i-07db9e2f61d100\",\"name\":\"InstanceId\"}],\"Period\":60,\"EvaluationPeriods\":2,\"ComparisonOperator\":\"GreaterThanThreshold\",\"Threshold\":70.0,\"TreatMissingData\":\"\",\"EvaluateLowSampleCountPercentile\":\"\"}}",
        "Timestamp": "2019-08-26T19:20:52.403Z",
        "SignatureVersion": "1",
        "Signature": "UeWhS==",
        "SigningCertUrl": "https://sns.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-63f9.pem",
        "UnsubscribeUrl": "https://sns.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:49:Alarm-test:dfe-1c4b-4db9",
        "MessageAttributes": {}
      }
    }
  ]
}

I am using @types/aws-lambda NPM package to identify the shape of the event received as mentioned in the AWS documentation.
The event received in the lambda from SNS topic matches the SNSEvent interface defined in aws-lambda package. But I am not able to find any interface or type for the cloudwatch alarm embedded in the Message field in this event. Is there any type available for this or should I create custom type for this?
